# Webform-civiCRM equivalent for Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, webform-civicrm

I'm new to CiviCRM and I have a colleague who's using it with Drupal and loving the Webform-CiviCRM integration. I myself use Wordpress and would like to be able to stay with Wordpress but I understand that Webform-CiviCRM is Drupal based. We'd be using forms as a way for new users to register with our organization and I'm wondering how we can achieve similar functionality with forms while staying with Wordpress. Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing exactly what features you are looking for. There is nothing quite like webform-civicrm in WP, but depending on what you're trying to do, there may be ways to do it.

Comment: The component that I'm looking to replicate is the creation of registration forms. Is there a certain form plugin that integrates with CiviCRM which would pass along the submitted information to the Civi database?

Answer (score 11):

CiviCRM has a built in form builder which are called [Profiles](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/organising-your-data/profiles/). It's not as powerful as Webform integration, but may fit your needs.

If not, the equivalent for WordPress would be [Caldera Forms with CiviCRM integration](https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm not familiar with what you mean by, "in the shape of Profiles" but I assume that as I become more acquainted with CiviCRM that will mean something to me :-)

Comment: @Rochel I added a link to profiles documentation to this answer. Worth a read.

Answer (score 7):

The CiviCRM Gravity Forms integration by [CiviVIP](http://civivip.com/) is looking like a good first step towards full integration with CiviCRM. Currently it has integration with multiple contacts (that can be linked via relationships) and activities. I think event registration and contributions are on the list of features currently being developed. Nathan's [presentation at CiviCon](https://denver2015.civicrm.org/sessions/what-you-should-know-about-integrating-wordpress-civicrm) was a good demo of the current integration and insight into what is possible for the future.

Would be super awesome if WP / Civi folks would support the project and deploy the integration on their sites and provide feedback to the developers

Comment: Thanks! I came across the CiviVIP site in doing some research on this and I was hoping they'd have more information available on their site. Seems that "checkout" is the only next step to finding out details.

Comment: I'm sure more WP devs would contribute if the plugin was FOSS :-(

Answer (score 6):

A new alternative to Gravity Forms is [Caldera Forms with CiviCRM integration](https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm).  Unlike the Gracity Forms integration, development is active and it now far surpasses Gravity Forms integration in functionality.

Comment: Updating that the latest version of Caldera Forms CiviCRM (CFC) can process membership and donations too, there's a [blog post about it here](https://civicrm.org/blog/danaskallman/caldera-forms-civicrm-cfc-for-donations-and-membership).

Comment: CFC is really a good choice. However with [cf-civicrm-formprocessor](https://github.com/civimrf/cf-civicrm-formprocessor) now there is also a second Integration that connects Caldera Forms with the form processor extension which gives you even more flexibility in handling submissions, prefilling forms and much more. It is even possible to use both integrations together.

Comment: @andreas that's great to know!  You may also be interested in artfulrobot's "Inlay" extension, which allows defining your own backend, and his and my join work on [inlayfp](https://github.com/artfulrobot/inlayfp).  InlayFP lets you generate a form based on a Form Processor - which is great when you need a static site, or a non-WP/Drupal/etc. site.

Answer (score 4):

I'd be more than happy to answer any questions you have regarding the Gravity Forms to CiviCRM integration available at CiviVIP. I apologize that there isn't more documentation readily available. Something we're actively working on. Please feel free to reach out through the chat or by email nate@wapix.co or ask specific questions here.

Right now the functionality allows you to create contact, create relationships between contacts and create activities. We don't have any of the other components integrated yet. (namely events, contributions, cases, etc.) We are getting close with contributions however. That would be the next step in our roadmap.

This is a pretty new solution so I appreciate your patience in checking it out. We launched it at CiviCon 2015.

Answer (score 3):

There are also good projects for WP/Civi integration by christainwach (He gave a good talk / demo at CiviCON in London) on GitHub, here: https://github.com/christianwach.
Good luck, Hope it goes well!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are specifically interested in registration forms, I suggest you begin with the basic functionality of [CiviEvent](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/events/creating-an-event/). Out of the box CiviCRM can:

- Create a registration form where members of the public can sign up for your event.
- Allows you to include this form in a WP page/post via shortcodes.
- Create complicated pricing structures and allow people to pay online and/or choose to pay later.

Comment: Didn't mean to be misleading. When I say registration I don't only mean for events I mean signing up to receive services or provide services with our organization. I'm not sure that CiviEvent would be appropriate for that. Thanks!

Comment: Using [Event Organiser](https://wordpress.org/plugins/event-organiser/) with this [CiviCRM integration plugin](https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-event-organiser) is useful to have Event listing in WP and link and manage registration with CiviEvent.