# CiviEvent: Event info and registration form on one page?

Tags: wordpress, civievent, registration, online-registration

Right now, when I create an event, there is one web page for the info about the event, with buttons to click to get to the online registration page with a form where they fill in their name and email and actually register for the event. Is it possible to have the event info and registration form on one page, so they don't have to click a button and go to a different page, but can just fill in their name and email and click "register" one time and be done? This is a free event, so payment is not a concern.

I'm running CiviCRM in WordPress 4.7.4, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is skip the Event info page. You can link directly to:
/civicrm/event/register?id=1&reset=1

For the info:
In Drupal you'd add a block on the register page to show the Event info/details. I'm all but certain that Wordpress has a concept similar to Drupal's 'blocks'.

Answer (score 1):

Under the Online Registration tab, there is a section called Registration Screen. Under the Introductory Text field, you can put your event information there. It accepts full HTML so you can format and style how you want. As KarinG mentioned, you'd then just link directly to the registration page. We have started to do this with our events as we found having the user go through multiple pages just to get to a registration page is cumbersome.

Drupal also has a CiviCRM-Webform Integration module that gives you more control where you can add everything to one page -- it looks like there was discussion about a Wordpress equivalent a couple years ago: [Webform-civiCRM equivalent for Wordpress?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/787/webform-civicrm-equivalent-for-wordpress). Not sure what the status of that is now.

Comment: That's right there is an HTML field on the online registration screen itself too!