# CiviCRM Shortcodes button no longer shows up on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, button

The CiviCRM shortcodes button on WordPress is no longer showing up on my install and I cannot determine why.

What could cause this functionality to disappear?

[image]

Comment: pls add a bit more explanation about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't have CiviCRM button on my pages I wanna to add this button to my pages besides the Caldera Form.

Comment: Check all of your user permissions. You may need to select the one for accessing the CIviCRM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webform-civiCRM equivalent for Wordpress?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/787/webform-civicrm-equivalent-for-wordpress)

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I think this is actually a different question

Comment: Rasha, try to think of some things you might have changed recently that might have caused your CiviCRM button to go away and edit your question to include them. See if it's still installed, check the settings, permissions, etc. How long was it working before it disappeared? Try to give us more information. Right now, your question is too broad with not enough info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have the CiviCRM Admin Utilities plugin active, make sure you have selected the post types on which the button is allowed.

Comment: Thanks, This was a good point and also solve my problem.

Comment: Would be good if you therefore Accept Christian's answer